# Why can't I select new Java class in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm new to IntelliJ Idea (Community Edition). I'm trying to create a new Java class. But there's no Java Class option in dialogue (even though HTML File and Kotlin Script are included". There's only "File". Any idea how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: What else is in that folder? Is folder marked as a source folder?

Comment: Please see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000622524-Where-is-the-new-java-class-option-

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, it's Java project.

Comment: @ZinWinHtet, I'm not asking what the project is.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you had not setup JDK. can you please verify if jdk is set . this should help you: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#jdk

Comment: I installed jdk already bro.. openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_232-b09)

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPfqX.png)

first, create a java project. i think you haven't select any java project